# Decode both map and array json

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, dictionary, go

External API returns empty array if no items:

```
{"items":[]}
```

...or map with items:

```
{"items":{"1": {...}, "2": {...}}}
```

How can I decode both of them? I tried using this struct:

```
var response struct {
    Items map[string]Item
    Array []Item `json:"items"`
}
```

But it doesn't work.

**UPDATE:** Best if both (array and object) will produce a `map[string]Item` (empty and filled)

Comment: Please notice what I want to **decode** existing json and I have **one key** and **two types** of the value

Comment: @Amd Read the question, please
Array is always empty, it should be empty `map[string]Item{}`
Object is always filled, so it should be filled `map[string]Item{...}`

Comment: @Amd it should decode `array` or `object` in `one` field of type `map[string]Item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to unmarshall to a variable type, the easiest way is to unmarshal into a `map[string]interface{}` and type-assert (or in this case, type-switch) your way out.

```
func Unmarshal(data []byte) (map[string]Item, error) {
    var d struct {
        Items interface{} `json:"items"`
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &d); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    switch dv := d.Items.(type) {
    case []interface{}:
        if len(dv) == 0 {
            return nil, nil
        }
    case map[string]interface{}:
        m := make(map[string]Item)
        for k, v := range dv {
            m[k] = Item(v)
        }
        return m, nil
    }
    // fallthrough return if different type, or non-empty array
    // Could have put this in a default case, but this catches non-empty arrays too
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected type in json")
}
```

Here's an example showing it works for both of your provided examples: https://play.golang.org/p/c0oZX2-xpN

Answer (score 0):

Try this working code (A):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Item int

type response struct {
    Items map[string]Item `json:"Items"`
    Array []Item          `json:"Array"`
}

func main() {
    var d response
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"Items":{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3},"Array":[]}`), &d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

output:

```
{map[C:3 A:1 B:2] []}
```

---

Try this working code (B):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Item int

type response struct {
    Items map[string]Item `json:"Items"`
    //Array []Item          `json:"Array"`
}

func main() {
    var d response
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"Items":{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3},"Array":[]}`), &d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

output:

```
{map[C:3 A:1 B:2]}
```

---

You may use `json.Marshal` and `json.Unmarshal`, like this working code (C):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Item int

type response struct {
    Items map[string]Item `json:"Items"`
    Array []Item          `json:"Array"`
}

func main() {
    var test = response{
        Items: map[string]Item{"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3},
        Array: []Item{},
    }
    body, err := json.Marshal(test)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body)) // {"Items":{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3},"Array":[]}

    var d response
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

output:

```
{"Items":{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3},"Array":[]}
{map[A:1 B:2 C:3] []}
```

---

You may Unmarshal `{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3}` to `map[A:1 B:2 C:3]`
and  `"[1,2,3]"` to `[1 2 3]`, like this working code (D):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Item int

type response1 map[string]Item
type response2 []Item

func main() {
    var d response1
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3}`), &d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(d) // map[A:1 B:2 C:3]

    var d2 response2
    err2 := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`[1,2,3]`), &d2)
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
    fmt.Println(d2) // [1 2 3]
}
```

output:

```
map[A:1 B:2 C:3]
[1 2 3]
```